# What is the exact meaning of ionic and covalent character?

Tags: bond

In my textbook, it is written that 'Even in case of covalent bond between two Hydrogen atoms there is some ionic character.'
Didn't get that.

Comment: Sounds like nonsense to me. I mean, they may have had in mind things like polarizability, induced dipoles... but still, this just sounds ugly. If H-H is not a 100% covalent bond, then what is?

Comment: What the book means is that the canonical forms $\ce{H-H <-> H^{-} ... H^{+} <-> H^{+} ... H^{-}}$ all contribute to the true picture of bonding in $\ce{H2}$, even if we often imagine the bond as purely covalent. This is true. It is possible to prove that calculations which ignore the ionic resonance structures result in a worse approximation of experimental energy levels. One of the computational/theoretical chemistry users around here can probably give a great answer regarding this.

Comment: Resonance like thing in H2 molecule?

Comment: Hmm I think you are right. So is this London Forces?